# Is there a way to add translate-z-[ ] utility class

Tags: tailwind-css

I would like to add translate-z-[] utility class to my tailwindcss classes so I could use parallax scrolling effects with perspective and translateZ, is there a way to generate these classes (add something like --tw-translate-z variable at the end on tailwinds transform class)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can create [plugins](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#dynamic-utilities) for custom utilities

You config should have something like this

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

module.exports = {
  theme: {},
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ matchUtilities, theme }) {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'translate-z': (value) => ({
            '--tw-translate-z': value,
            transform: ` translate3d(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y), var(--tw-translate-z)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y))`,
          }), // this is actual CSS
        },
        { values: theme('translate'), supportsNegativeValues: true }
      )
    })
  ],
}
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/IZBe0oGl1f)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've read the docs now and this will 100% do the job.

Comment: How to add negative values so `-translate-z-1` also works? _It works with abritrary values, like `translate-z-[-1px]`, but doesn't look as nice.

Comment: @oemera Good catch, thanks! Change default values form `{values: theme('translate')}` into `{values: theme('translate'), supportsNegativeValues: true}` - I've updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can add *tailwind-3dtransforms* plugin into your tailwindcss setup and start using 3d transforms. With this plugin, you can use classes such as `translate-z-10`, `translate-z-20` ...etc. Further, it also allows other transforms like rotate, scale, flip in all 3 axes.

Using this plugin you can add following if you want to translate 250px on Z axis,

```html
<div class="transform translate-z-[250px]></div>
```

Or tailwind defaults for translate are also possible. For instance, you can do following,

```html
<div class="transform translate-z-20"></div>
```

You can [check the documentation here](https://xpd-kasun.github.io/tailwind-3dtransform-plugin) and [github repository here](https://github.com/XPD-Kasun/tailwind-3dtransform-plugin).

- *I'm the author of tailwind-3dtransform-plugin.*